# Percorrer um Array e verificar se algum elemento é vazio

Tags: php, array, iterator

Existe alguma função nativa do PHP para percorrer um `array` e verificar se algum elemento desse array é vazio `null`?

Observem o código abaixo:

```php
if(isset($_POST['btnCriaModelo'])){

  $instArray  = $_POST['idInstrucao'];
  $orderArray = $_POST['ordem'];

  for ($i=1; $i < count($instArray) ; $i++) { 

     /*
       Aqui é onde pensei em fazer essa verificação mas não consigo criar uma lógica.
       A variável auxilar $i começa com o valor 1 por que naturalmente no meu código
       o primeiro elemento destes vetores acima são vazios, porém todos os outros elementos
       não podem se quer um está vazios 
     */

  }               

}
```

O motivo pelo qual preciso fazer esta verificação é para fazer uma validação com o PHP. Caso haja algum elemento do vetor vazio eu não rodo o loop de inserção no meu banco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solução mais simples para o seu problema é:

```
$valido = (false === array_search(false , $instArray, false));
```

Exemplo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wuy-79m

Answer (score 8):

Tem muitas formas de comprovar se o elemento é vazio. Por exemplo, seguindo este esquema:

```
if (elemento é vazio) {
    faça qualquer coisa
}
```

Deve definir o que significa "vazio": significa `null`? `0` é vazio? o booleano `false` é vazio? uma cadeia vazia (`""`) é vazio? e um espaço `" "`?

Então tem uma infinidade de métodos de construir seu condicional, cada um retornará `true` ou `false` segundo o conteúdo da variável, alguns consideram `0` vazio e outros não...

A seguir alguns exemplos.

#### [Função is_null()](http://php.net/is-null)

Retornará `true` apenas se o elemento não existe ou é igual a `null`.

```
if (is_null($elemento)) {
    // O elemento é vazio, faça qualquer coisa
}
```

#### [Função empty()](http://php.net/empty)

Retornará `true` se o elemento não existe, é igual a `null`, se é igual a `false`, se é igual a `""`, se é igual a `0`, se é igual a `0.0`, se é igual a `"0"` ou se é igual a `array()` (array vazio).

```
if (empty($elemento)) {
    // O elemento é vazio, faça qualquer coisa
}
```

#### [Função isset()](http://php.net/isset)

Retornará `false` apenas se o elemento não existe, ou é igual a `null`.

```
if (!isset($elemento)) {
    // O elemento é vazio, faça qualquer coisa
}
```

#### Operadores lógicos

Também pode utilizar operadores lógicos para comprovar a igualdade com uma ou várias das possíveis acepções de "vazio". Por exemplo:

```
if ($elemento === 0) {
    // O elemento é exatamente o número inteiro "zero", faça qualquer coisa
}

if ($elemento === "") {
    // O elemento é exatamente um string vazio, faça qualquer coisa
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar um [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) nativo do php.

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php

$entry = array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => false,
    2 => -1,
    3 => null,
    4 => ''
);

print_r(array_filter($entry));
```

A saída será esta:

```
Array
(
  [0] => foo
  [2] => -1
}
```

Ou seja, o `array_filter` ignorou o que tem valores **false**, **null** e **empty**.

Neste caso você pode iterar sobre os resultados válidos.

Answer (score 3):

Em arrays associativas o melhor é usar um [**foreach**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) uma vez que as chaves da sua array não são numeráveis onde um ciclo `for` possa ser usado como você têm na sua pergunta:

Asim um exemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnCriaModelo'])) {
    $instArray = $_POST['idInstrucao'];
    $orderArray = $_POST['ordem'];

    foreach($instArray as $chave => $valor){ //se não quer a chave pode usar só ($instArray as $valor)
        if($valor != ''){  
            // fazer qualquer coisa no caso de não ser vazio
            echo 'A idInstrucao é: '.$chave.' e o seu valor é: '.$valor;
        }
    }
}
```

### [Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2yi-rd4)

Answer (score 3):

Caso você vá percorrer toda a array você pode utilizar um `is_null` para validar se é nulo ou não e `empty` se está vazio ou não.

```
<?php
$arr = array('teste', 'teste 2', 123, '', null, false);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (is_null($value)) {
        echo 'Nulo';
    } else if (empty($value)) {
        echo 'Vazio';
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Lembrando que o [empty](http://www.php.net/empty) valida se a variável está vazia, sendo assim como o albertedevigo falou que caso esteja como  `0`, `false` ou `""` ele retorna `true`

Answer (score 2):

Se você só quer encontrar a primeira ocorrência, você pode usar as funções [in_array](http://www.php.net/in_array) ou [array_search](http://www.php.net/array_search).

Se você quer encontrar todas as ocorrências caso haja mais do que uma, o melhor mesmo é atravessar o array usando [foreach](http://www.php.net/foreach).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode optar por varrer o `array` e encerrar o loop assim que o array encontrar um elemento vazio:

```
$erro = false;
foreach ( $meuArray as $valor ) :
  if ( empty($valor) || $valor === null ) :
    $erro = 'Opa! Você está com campos vazios!';
    break; // Esse break encerrará o foreach!
  endif;
endforeach;

if ( !$erro ) :
  // Você pode gravar no banco!
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `in_array` do `PHP` como no exemplo a seguir:

```php
if(in_array(NULL, $variavel)){
   /*Tem valor NULL em uma variável*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso, já foi falado anteriormente sobre a função **empty**, que verifica se o valor é null, "", 0, array().

A função **array_filter()** remove qualquer um destes citados dentro do array passado como parâmetro.

Em poucas linhas, existe uma maneira de verificar se existe alguma valor vazio dentro de um array, isto é, comparando o array original com o array "filtrado"

```
<?php

$array = array('teste', 'outro teste', array(), 0);

if($array === array_filter($array)){
   echo 'Não existem elementos vazios';
}
else{
   echo 'Existem elementos vazios';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$posicoesVazias = array_keys($array, '', TRUE);

if(empty($posicoesVazias)){

    // Sem itens vazios

}else{

    echo "Os itens " . implode(', ', $posicoesVazias) . " estão vazios.";

}
```