# Definir um retorno aleatório para uma função

Tags: php

Estou criando uma função que recebe um retorno x de outra função e queria testar as possibilidades para evitar erros.

```
$array = [1,2];
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $retorno[$i] =  funcao();
    $i++;
}
echo "Conteudo do array: ";
echo var_dump($retorno);
echo "</br>";
function funcao(){
    return 'falhou' || NULL;
}
$valido = false === array_search(false , $retorno, false);
echo "Teste: ";
var_dump($valido);
```

Quero aleatorizar esse retorno, podendo ser uma string tipo `'função falhou'` ou `NULL`.

[Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fuf6-dx2g)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondendo diretamente a sua pergunta, é possível retornar um valor aleatório.

A solução abaixo reordena o array aleatoriamente e devolve o primeiro item.

```
function funcao(){
    $result = array('falhou', NULL);
    shuffle($result);
    return $result[0];
}
```

Ou algo mais simples, caso seja apenas 2 valores:

```
function funcao(){
    return rand(0,1) ? 'falhou' : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Vou votar na sua resposta porque achei mais sucinta, uns 20 mins depois de postar a pergunta tinha chegado a mesma conclusão que a sua, randomizando o retorno, esperei mais respostas pra ver se possuía algo mais direto, do tipo `return 'falhou' or NULL`

Answer (score 2):

Minha resposta é com base no seu código e na sua pergunta, mas gostaria de frizar que achei a lógica da linha que seta a variável $valido muito confusa.

Basicamente usei a função **rand(int min, int max)** para sortear números e retornar 'falhou' ou NULL aleatoriamente.

```
<?php

function funcao()
{
    // sorteia um número $n entre 1 ou 2 aleatoriamente
    $n = rand (1 , 2);

    // se o $n sorteado for igual a 1, retorna 'falhou'
    // se o $n sorteado for igual a 2, retorna NULL
    if($n==1)
    {
        return 'falhou';    
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;   
    }
}


$array = [1,2];
$i = 0;

foreach ($array as $value) 
{
    $retorno[$i] =  funcao();
    $i++;
}

echo "Conteudo do array: ";
echo var_dump($retorno);
echo "</br>";


// ATENÇÃO: A lógica dessa linha abaixo é muito confusa e acho que vc deveria reescrevê-la para algo mais inteligível.
// A função array_search retorna o q foi procurado, ou false se não achar o que procurou. 
// O terceiro parâmetro com valor false diz para não comparar tipo*
// Testei aqui e:
// $valido será true se ambos os elementos em retorno forem iguais a 'falhou'
// $valido será false em demais casos, isso pq null é considerado um equivalente de false quando não se verifica tipo
// se o terceiro parâmetro estivesse como true:
//    $valido sempre seria true pq array_search sempre iria falhar e retornaria false que é === false e a comparação retorna true.
$valido = false === array_search(false , $retorno, true);

echo "Teste: ";
var_dump($valido);
```

Comment: Sobre `$valido = false === array_search(false , $retorno, false);`
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3390/percorrer-um-array-e-verificar-se-algum-elemento-%C3%A9-vazio :)

Comment: Os retornos dessa função `funcao()` serão *SEMPRE* 'falhou' caso falhar ou NULL caso funcionar
Nessa linha `$valido = false ===........` que eu peguei de uma outra resposta aqui do stack, que inclusive era o ponto onde queria chegar com essa pergunta, testo apenas se existe algum elemento NULL dentro do array

Comment: @FilipeMoraes, o ponto que eu queria chegar era na aleatorização do retorno pra poder validar essa função, depois que eu elaborei a função de retorno vindo como algo que seria na vida real "aleatoriamente" ai eu ví que ela não atendia a minha necessidade e a adaptei :D

Comment: [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gue4-98ij) `$valido = !array_search(false , $instArray, false);` não funciona

Comment: [fiddle2](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5eib-fch2) `$valido = false === array_search('falhou' , $retorno, true);` funciona

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio tens razão, a função `array_search` devolve `False` ou o índice, que nesse caso pode ser `0`, daí a comparação com o `false` usando 3 iguais `===`, comparando o valor e tipo, já que `0` pode ser interpretado no PHP como `false`.